# At what moments can I get info from an intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I send an intent with information to start an activity. Now, instead of retrieving the info in the onCreate method, can I retrieve it after that moment? For example, when I click a button in the new activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I think you can if you write it this way:

```
YourActivity.this.getIntent().getExtras();
```

Comment: Using the same case. This time I start the new activity, but i don't press the button. I close the app, then open it again and press the button. Does it work? In other words, when the info on the intent dissapears?

Comment: I think it should. I did not test.
If not, you can override the method onStop() and save it to a variable at this time.
(onStop() is a Android lifecycle method, it is executed when you minimize the acvtivity or go to another activity)

Answer (score 1):

`getIntent().getExtras()` yields the data in your current Activity.

If you want to pass this data to a new Activity you have to read them and write into a new Intent.

Answer (score -1):

If the first activity is made as singleton then you can get the Intent data from the only Activity's instance.

Or you can make another singleton class just to hold that data for you.